# How to map AfNetworking response object (JSON) to custom class?

Tags: ios, json, xcode5, afnetworking

I'm getting a *JSON* as response for a *POST* method using `AFNetworking`.
I need to map the *JSON* to a custom class and the create an object containing values from the *JSON*.

**JSON String**

```
{
branch =     {
    address = "";
    email = "";
    globalId = 174;
    id = 0;
    mobile = 9846147442;
    name = "Sathish Clininc Branch1";
    netMdId = 132;
    numberOfDevices = 0;
    organisationName = "<null>";
    passPhrase =         (
    );
    phone = 04872279166;
    status = active;
};
error = "<null>";
netmd =     {
    globalId = 132;
    headOfficeAddress = "";
    headOfficeEmail = "sreejith@gmail.com";
    headOfficeMobile = "";
    headOfficeName = Koorkenchery;
    headOfficePhone = "";
    id = 0;
    name = "Sathish Clinic";
    ownerAddress = "";
    ownerEmail = "sreejith@gmail.com";
    ownerFirstName = Sathish;
    ownerLastName = Chandran;
    ownerMobile = "";
    ownerPhone = "";
    password = "aW8oFWDMOJUrIV3l7R7hqQ==";
    status = active;
    userName = sathish;
    userType = owner;
};
primary = 1;
retrieveAppointments =     (
);
retrieveDoctorsList =     (
);
retrievePatients =     (
);
retrieveScheduleList =     (
);
success = 1;
user =     (
);    }
```

**Custom Class**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ErrorDTO.h"
#import "NetMdBranchDTO.h"
#import "NetMdDTO.h"
@interface NetMdActivationResponseDTO : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong)ErrorDTO* error;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL success;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NetMdBranchDTO* branch;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NetMdDTO* netmd;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* user;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* retrieveDoctorsList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* retrievePatients;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* retrieveScheduleList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* retrieveAppointments;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL primary;

@end
```

Answer (score 6):

You can boost your value object with [Mantle](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle). It would be easier to maintain all transformations.

Answer (score 5):

If your JSON keys match your custom class's properties then it is straight forward:

1. Deserialize your JSON data into an NSDictionary using the `NSJSONSerialization` class.
2. Fill your custom objects properties using `[object setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:deserializedDictionary]`

If the keys do not match than set the properties like `object.user = deserializedDictionary[@"userName"]`

Another option is to allow custom object to accept all kinds of keys and do the mapping within the object by overriding `-setValue:ForKey:`

Answer (score 1):

Use  [JSON Accelerator](http://nerdery.com/json-accelerator) generate your classes add to code execute

If you want to deal it by yourself

```
{} : Represents object/Dictionary
[] : Represents array
```

Dive in write every drill down and get what you require